# How to Pass Image to a Button in UserControl using Dependency Property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I have created an UserControl. It has a Button and a textblock. I want to pass an Image to that Button using Dependency property. But when I try to call that usercontrol in some other page, its showing some error. This is my code..

User Control.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="....UserControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"            
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" >
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Border Grid.Row="0"
        Name="borMain"
        Style="{StaticResource ButtonImageTextBorderStyle}"
        MouseEnter="borMain_MouseEnter"
        MouseLeave="borMain_MouseLeave"
        PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="borMain_MouseLeftButtonDown" >
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup Name="MouseStates">
                <VisualState Name="MouseEnter">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation To="Black"
                          Duration="0:0:00.1"
                          Storyboard.TargetName="borMain"
                          Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush.Color" />
                        <ColorAnimation To="Black"
                          Duration="0:0:00.1"
                          Storyboard.TargetName="borMain"
                          Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" />
                        <ThicknessAnimation To="4,1,4,4"
                              Duration="0:0:00.1"
                              Storyboard.TargetName="borMain"
                              Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState Name="MouseLeave" />
                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                    <VisualTransition To="MouseLeave" />
                    <VisualTransition To="MouseEnter" />
                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <Button Content="{Binding Path=AppBarContent}"                  
         Style="{StaticResource ButtonImageTextImageStyle}" />
    </Border>

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"
           Name="tbText"
           Style="{StaticResource ButtonImageTextTextBlockStyle}"
           Text="{Binding Path=Text}" />
   </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

UserControl.xaml.cs:

```
 [DefaultEvent("Click")]
   public partial class SystemUnitUserControl : UserControl
   {
      public UserControl()
      {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
      }
    #region Text Property
    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(TextProperty, value);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                tbText.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }


    #region AppBarContent Property
    public Image AppBarContent
    {
        get { return (Image)GetValue(AppBarContentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AppBarContentProperty, value); }
    }

      public static readonly DependencyProperty AppBarContentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("AppBarContent", typeof(Image),  typeof(SystemUnitUserControl), null);
    #endregion

    #region MouseLeftDown Event
    private void borMain_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        RaiseClick(e);
    }
    #endregion

    #region Click Event Procedure
    public delegate void ClickEventHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e);
    public event ClickEventHandler Click;

    protected void RaiseClick(RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (null != Click)
            Click(this, e);
    }
    #endregion

    #region Visual State Animations
    private void borMain_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToElementState(borMain, "MouseEnter", true);
    }

    private void borMain_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToElementState(borMain, "MouseLeave", true);
    }
    #endregion
```

I am calling this Usercontrol in other page.

Window1.xaml:

```
...
 xmlns:my="clr-namespace:....UserControls"
...

         <my:UserControl x:Name="actionRectDuct"   
                         AppBarContent="F:\..\..\Assets\offline.jpg"
                         Text="Button 1" />
```

Its not going into that page. Its showing the following error..

A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: 'Set property 'UnitUserControl.AppBarContent' threw an exception.' Line number '38' and line position '41'.

I want to pass image on the AppBarContent.. how can i do this??

Comment: `AppBarContent` is of type `Image` and you are setting it to string.

Comment: #region AppBarContent Property
    public Image AppBarContent
    {
        get { return (Image)GetValue(AppBarContentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AppBarContentProperty, value); }
    }

      public static readonly DependencyProperty AppBarContentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("AppBarContent", typeof(Image),  typeof(SystemUnitUserControl), null);
    #endregion

Comment: Nope. I setted to Image only.. I didnt get your point

Comment: if you want to pass a file name the perhaps you could consider `ImageSource` instead of an `Image` here. an ImageSource has converter from string. or you can write a converter to convert the image path string to image.

Comment: @JohnPaul - File path and image are completely different things. You need to pass Image object created using file path. Either change the DP to type string Or bind Image object from UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is how you can do the same with your code

```
     <my:UserControl x:Name="actionRectDuct"
                     Text="Button 1" >   
         <my:UserControl.AppBarContent>
             <Image Source="F:\..\..\Assets\offline.jpg" />
         </my:UserControl.AppBarContent>
     </my:UserControl>
```

instead of passing an string to the `AppBarContent` property which accepts an Image, we'll now pass the an instance of Image having the source as the desired file. so as long as the source is correct you'll be able to get the desired image in SystemUnitUserControl

Comment: I am unable to use Click event for this Usercontrol. Could you help me to Assign Click event for my UserControl???

Comment: I am glad it worked for you. As now you have a new question may I ask you to post a separate question with necessary details. like where did you define the button? where you want to receive the event (event handler)? and any other necessary details. Thanks